# Using Behavioral Driven Development in Automation Framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tdd, bdd

I have an experience of developing Automation frameworks using **Selenium Web-driver**,**Java** and **TestNG/ Junit**. In my *Automation frameworks* I used to simply automate the manual test cases and the manual efforts of testers.

Now I have been assigned a Task where i need to develop the *Automation Framework* using *Behavioral Driven Development*.

*What are the things I should know before i start BDD in Automation frameworks*

&

*What will make my framework different from my previous frameworks?*

Comment: Check with [QMetry Automation Framewok](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf). You can start with [blank project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project). You also can follow [step-by-step tutorial](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/) find the [wiki pages here](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are the things I should know before i start BDD in Automation frameworks

I will consider that you know how to work with BDD, so I'll stick literally to what's in the question.

- First you must consider the roles and the people you'll engage in this BBD automation framework. If they're all technical people or if there are mix of technical and non-technical people involved in defining the scenarios and examples.
- Then you must consider the scope of your automation tests. What will they test: web only? desktop browsers, apps, mobile browsers?
- Do you have a test-launching language preferrence ?

Once you have the answers to that, then you'll have to look for a really important thing to look for when promoting BDD: tooling.

The non-technical and technical skills of your co-workers will have a great impact on the tool which will connect the tests specificacion to test implementation. There are many tools and some require less to more technical skills (althought they are simple): DaSpec, JBehave, Cucumber, calabash, BeHat... There are many and you must look for the one best fitting you company.

And then the scope will give you the other tooling you'll need, If you want to test only on desktop browsers, Selenium the de-facto standard for this. If you want to go mobile too selenium has support for that, but you'll need additional tooling like Selendroid and/or Appium. For native clients automation there are manny alternatives too, a quick search here or google will spit a lot of results.

Once you have made your choices. The next step is to measure the impact of BDD methodology on your company, the best bet (in my short experience with BDD) is to start with a project which has loose requirements if any. BDD could shine with that. You'll have to measure that in the first stages BDD has a steep ramp of effort as you put down your infrastructure and code and the first teams to work on it.

When you have the infrastructure and some initial code. The thing is to start with the BDD liturgy and accomodate that on your project's liturgy. Please be very helpful and be open to the opinions of everyone.

> What will make my framework different from my previous frameworks?

I don't know if you're asking about an automation framework or your company's framework, sorry :(